# Sorting and coloring excel file via python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import openpyxl
from itertools import combinations
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

import json 

def readExcel():
    df = pd.read_excel('tedarikci.xlsx')

    # Tüm isimleri bir Python listesine ata
    isimler = df['Müşteri/tedarikçi ismi'].tolist() #names

    # output_list = []
    # İsimleri karşılaştır

    def searchInDict(dataDict,item):
        if item in dataDict.keys():
            return False
        else:
            for parent in dataDict.keys():
                if item  in dataDict[parent]:
                    return False
            return True
            
    benzerIsimler = {} #similarNames
    print(isimler) #names

    counter = 0
    for i,item in enumerate(isimler):
        print(i)
        if searchInDict(benzerIsimler,item):
            print(item)
            benzerIsimler[item] = []
            for j,item2 in enumerate(isimler):
                if item != item2:
                    
                    score = SequenceMatcher(None, item, item2).ratio()
                    if score > 0.9:
                        benzerIsimler[item].append(item2)
                        

    for i in benzerIsimler.keys():
        print(benzerIsimler[i])

    with open("dataMusteri.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(benzerIsimler, outfile)


def printExcel():
    benzerIsimler = None

    with open("dataMusteri.json", "r") as outfile:
        benzerIsimler = json.load(outfile)
        
    dataframe = openpyxl.load_workbook("tedarikci.xlsx")
    
    # Define variable to read sheet
    dataframe1 = dataframe.active

    sortedRows = []

    for item in benzerIsimler.keys():
        print(item)
        for row in dataframe1.iter_rows():
            if row[0].value == item :
                sortedRows.append(row)
                break
        
        for item2 in benzerIsimler[item]:
            for row in dataframe1.iter_rows():
                if row[0].value == item :
                    sortedRows.append(row)
                    break
        
    
    print(sortedRows)

    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.append(["Müşteri/tedarikçi ismi","E-posta","Müşteri/tedarikçi grubu","TL Bakiye ",   "USD Bakiye",   "EUR Bakiye",   "GBP Bakiye",   "Adres",    "İl",   "İlçe", "Telefon",  "Faks", "Vergi dairesi",    "Vergi numarası/TC kimlik no"])
    for row in sortedRows:
        row_with_values = [cell.value for cell in row]
        ws.append(row_with_values)
        
    wb.save("dilara.xlsx")


printExcel()
```

I am trying to sort the similar names on an excel file and after sorting I want to color the similar/same ones with the same color.

The code above is what I've done so far. I can sort but I can't paint the same/similar rows, my code paints all rows with the same color. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I have added an edit to the review queue to reformat your code sample since as posted it does not format all the code correctly. You should ensure the code sample indentation is correct. From a look through the code it doesn't look like the function **readExcel** is being used for this example, I retained it but if a piece of code is not  necessary it should not be included in the question. In the **printExcel** function there is this loop; **for item2 in benzerIsimler[item]:**. The variable **item2** is not used in the loop so there may be a bug in your code.

Comment: I don't see any code for filling rows with colour. It would have to be applied with the **ws** object when appending the row. However I've no idea what constitutes 'same/similar rows' so other than you'd need to create **PatternFill(s)** and iterate thru each cell in the row appended using **cell.fill** to apply, I can't comment on how the criteria for fill colour would be implemented.